# How to fix Null reference error when using Imagesharp for iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, imagesharp

The following code is throwing the null reference error:

```
 Image<SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats.Rgba32> myThumbnail = 
 SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(myBytes);
```

This error does not occur when running on Android. This leads me to believe it is an error caused by simply using ImageSharp on iOS. Is there any kind of special setup needed to use ImageSharp on iOS?

I am on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017. All I did to set up ImageSharp is I installed it using the nuget packet manager in VS2017.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I added the info that I do not get the error when running the code on Android. So, based on that, I do not think it is a duplicate. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Then you are missing some or the other native package

Comment: Yes I agree. Problem is what native package is that? I don't see one from SixLabors.ImageSharp

Comment: Then add it i mean you should be having it somewhere right?!

Comment: What exactly am I looking for? A DLL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188658/discussion-between-g-hakim-and-james-carter).